# Spaces between Hebrew letters

Tags: fonts, spacing, hebrew

I am writing in Hebrew, but my output doesn't look so good because the spaces between thew Hebrew words are too big. They are somehow bigger than usual, and also the font itself, just doesn't look good!

[image]

I am using MiKTeX distribution, and installed Culmus fonts. I may have also installed "ivritex" once, before. Could "ivritex" interfere with "Culmus" and cause the problem?

Has anyone encountered this problem or know how to solve it?
I have tested the hebrew on LyX too, and it also produces this problem.
I wanted to attach a picture to show the problem, but as I am a new user, I can't do it :-(

Comment: In order to add a picture, provide instead a link to it; a user with suitable privileges can add it for you. Can you also provide an example of code?

Comment: I used the same code as the following website: http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX and my picture is here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/600/hebo.png/

Comment: If you don't like spaces, this can be changed. But if you don't like the font, why not just use another? I tried this text with XeLaTeX and Times New Roman and this is the result: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy8lc.png Does it look better?

Comment: Do you find inter-word spaces too big for your taste also when paragraphs are not justified? e.g. in the last paragraph of your example? If the answer is 'no', then your issue is with the paragraph justification logic of TeX (which probably has a more accurate term for it); if it is 'yes', then your issue is with the minimum or default space between words which TeX users for the font that you're using. I think.

Comment: @EyalRozenberg: Please convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

PineApple, do you find inter-word spaces too big for your taste also when paragraphs are not justified? e.g. in the last paragraph of your example?

- **"No"**: Your issue is with the paragraph justification logic of TeX (for which there is probably a more accurate term).
- **"Yes"**: Your issue is with the minimum or default space between words which TeX uses for the current font.

Also, no, I believe 'ivritex' and 'culmus' cannot interfere with each other in a way which messes up spacing.

Comment: I didn't understand. how exactly can I change the spacing between the hebrew letters?

Comment: @roi.holtzman: This question is about inter-word, spacing, not intra-word (inter-letter) spacing. You can ask your questions separately...